# How can I convert array string of numbers to array of numbers? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I've got this array string

```
const str = "['595', '369']";
```

and I'll need this

```
const pos = [595, 369];
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried ? Take a look at `JSON.parse` for the begining.

Comment: Who-/whatever produces that string should produce valid JSON (or a valid JS array)

Comment: @MaximeGirou That's not JSON

Answer (score 2):

Using [`string#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [`string#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

- Remove anything that isn't an item of the list or `,`
- Use the `,`'s that we left to split the string into separate parts.
- Use `.map` to convert each string item in the array to a number.

```js
const str = "['595', '369']";

let array = str.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "").split(",").map(Number)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what is that /[^0-9,]/g thing? I mean what is it do.

Comment: @JakeBrasch It's a regular expression, in this case it is used to select everything that isn't a number or a comma so that it can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Get each number via regex, and then convert it to a number.

```js
const str = "['595', '369']";
const arr = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(arr)
```